# How to attach PDF to email using Swiftmailer in Symfony2

Tags: php, email, symfony, swiftmailer

I am sending an email using swiftmailer in symfony2, but I would like to add a specified PDF file as a file attachment to the email. How would I do that?

Here is my current code:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Hello Email')
    ->setFrom('send@example.com')
    ->setTo('recipient@example.com')
    ->setBody(
        $this->renderView(
            'HelloBundle:Hello:email.txt.twig',
            array('name' => $name)
        )
    )
;
$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have several options to attach a document to an email using swift mailer.

From the symfony doc:

```
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
      ->setFrom('from@example.com')
      ->setTo('to@example.com')
      ->setSubject('Subject')
      ->setBody('Body')
      ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('/path/to/a/file.zip'))
    ;

$this->getMailer()->send($message);
```

Comment: I had to write ->attach() before setBody()

Answer (score 6):

If you want to upload a file from buffer, you can do this:

```
$attach=getPdfFunction(); //binary
Swift_Attachment::newInstance($attach, 'document.pdf','application/pdf');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add your attachement using this line:

```
$message->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath($attach));
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code should do it:

```
$attachment = \Swift_Attachment::fromPath('subpath/to/attachment');
$message->attach($attachment);
```